# Possible to reload imported dictionaries?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-importlib

`from module import _dict` -> `_dict['new_key'] = 1` - and now, the same import in another file imports `_dict` with a previously non-existent key. This is a problem with `pytest` that runs several `test*.py` files, each mutating `_dict` - so e.g. `test_b` imports `_dict` modified by `test_a`.

A workaround is `_dict = copy.deepcopy(_dict)` before mutating - but suppose that isn't desired. `importlib.reload(module)` will not reload `_dict` - this said, is there any way to ensure the original `module._dict` is always imported?

---

**Example** (also [runnable code](https://repl.it/repls/SaneDesertedMode), without pytest).

```py
# configs.py
_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

```py
# non_test.py
from configs import _dict

class SomeClass():
   def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):
        self.a = a or _dict['a']
        self.b = b or _dict['b']
        del _dict['a']
```

```py
# test_a.py
def test_class():
    SomeClass()
```

```py
# test_b.py
def test_class():
    SomeClass()
```

Each `test*.py` has the following 'header' & 'footer':

```py
import pytest
from non_test import SomeClass
# test_*()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main([__file__, "-s"])
```

---

*Note*: the example isn't reflective of the actual context, within which I have a lot less flexibility. I'm not asking for a solution to 'the problem' itself - what I ask is right in the question's title. If it's "impossible" or there's nothing close to it, then that is the answer.

Comment: Sounds like _dict should be a class, which can then be instantiated multiple times.

Comment: @rdas It isn't a requirement - it's a result of `pytest` effectively running several `__main__`s where in practice there'd be only one.

Comment: @SiHa Using a class to hold dictionaries is a user-end inconvenience, and seems like a misuse of classes; the idea's to store configs as dicts, importable both internally and by users

Comment: I'm not sure there's multiple `__main__`s being executed, otherwise you wouldn't see this happening. There's a single `_dict` floating around, the one cached by `sys.modules`

Comment: @C.Nivs Right, didn't quite mean literally - basically whatever's imported is imported only once in practice, not multiple times, as in e.g. one TensorFlow session at a time.

Comment: I think what you might want is a function to return a config dict to each module that you would modify accordingly. This way you can have as many as you want and you don't have to explicitly `deepcopy` each one (though this is re-generating the dict, however you want to look at it)

Comment: Otherwise, this isn't really going to work within the context that I understand the problem to be, since it's kind of trying to "fix" python's import. You could write your own import hooks, but that seems to be an overkill solution IMO

Comment: @C.Nivs As in, define dicts within a function's body, then `from module import get_configs; configs = get_configs()`? That seems to be a fair workaround - but I wonder whether there's a non-hacky means of reloading a dictionary. Guess I'll rename the question

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon since you're looking for a solution that works in the context of `pytest`, can you add example test functions and show where `_dict` has the wrong values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`importlib.reload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) function to reload a module. Since `_dict` from `configs` is imported into module `non_test`, which is then imported into `test_b`, you should reload both `non_test` and `configs` to be able to both re-instantiate a new `configs._dict` and have it re-imported into `non_test`:

```
# test_b.py
import non_test
import configs
import importlib
importlib.reload(non_test)
importlib.reload(configs)

def test_class():
    SomeClass()
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/SaneDesertedMode

Comment: Err... how did this work. I'll double-check, but in the meantime, unsure how to interpret: _"If a module imports objects from another module using from … import …, calling reload() for the other module does not redefine the objects imported from it"_ Isn't this saying `reload(configs)` won't redefine `_dict`?

Comment: Oh, I think I know why this fails for me - I'll update the question with a more accurate example.

Comment: It's saying that if `_dict` is not defined directly in the module being reloaded, but rather imported from another module, reloading the module won't help redefine `_dict`. In other words, you should always reload the actual module that defines `_dict`.

Comment: It's important to realize that `_dict` is merely the reference point to the imported object in memory.  i.e. `from configs import _dict` might have an `id(_dict)` of `58907024`, and each subsequent attempt to import `_dict` will always reference back to the same object id.  That is, until `importlib.reload(configs)` is called - the existing `_dict` would still point to `id` `58907024`, but `config._dict` would now have a new id, and `from configs import _dict as new_dict` would make `new_dict` a new object reference as well.

Comment: Nice mini-IDE, by the way, quite convenient. Example closer to [my usage](https://repl.it/repls/SaneDesertedMode); I also tried `reload(configs)` within `non_test.py` [like so](https://repl.it/repls/AttractiveVerticalInstitute), but also fails.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I see. I've updated my answer accordingly then.

Comment: Ah, sense enough - abstracted Python in action. I've ultimately settled for `deepcopy` after figuring users may inevitably reproduce this, but still nice to know how to actually reload objects in modules - thanks.

Comment: If you could briefly explain why `reload(non_test)` is necessary, that'd help - does it have to do with namespaces? Or that the unreloaded `non_test` still refers to the old `_dict` so reloading it makes it reimport and hence point to the new `_dict`?

Comment: Yes exactly. If `non_test` isn't reloaded, the unreloaded `non_test` would still hold on to the old `_dict` in its namespace. Reloading it makes it re-import `_dict` from `configs`.